# Object select function

Tags: ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I don't understand why this happened but from one moment to the next, while selecting objects on my forms, object selection function when using the mouse changed forcing me to have to select (in a drag and drop way) all corners of each object. For example, if i have a rectangular shaped object i have to draw the ring around all four corners in order to select the object. Obviously this is very annoying when working on forms with many objects on it.  Prior to this, it was enough to just graze each object with the drag and drop selected.  Strangely when i take my databases to my work PC, this setting has not been activated and works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into Access Options/Object Designers
Under Form/Report design view
is an item for Selection behavior
Select Partially enclosed as opposed to Fully enclosed